# How to go to an a Specific HTML when a word is detected (Java)

Tags: javascript, html

Java I made an HTML called **hello.html** and now I want to use the `replace()` function in Java to go to the HTML page when the word **"Covid"** is detected on Google, I tried but it doesn't work for some reason, can you see where I am going wrong, or do I have to change my entire code?

```java
function redirectURL() {
    var specWord = getSpecificWord();

    switch(specWord) 
    {
      case 'corona':
        window.location.replace('hello.html');
        break;
      case 'covid':
        window.location.replace('hello.html');
        break;
      case 'covid-19':
        window.location.replace('hello.html');
        break;
      default:
        return true;
        break;
    }

    return false; // don't let the form submit
}

function getSpecificWord(Element) {
    var specificWord = "corona";
    return specificWord;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code does not work since you are not calling the `redirectURL` function.

Append `redirectURL()` to your code or use this instead:

```
(function redirectURL() {
  var specWord = getSpecificWord();
  switch (specWord) {
    case 'corona':
      window.location.replace('hello.html');
      break;
    case 'covid':
      window.location.replace('hello.html');
      break;
    case 'covid-19':
      window.location.replace('hello.html');
      break;
    default:
      return true;
      break;
  }
  return false; //don't let the form submit
})();

function getSpecificWord(Element) {
  var specificWord = 'corona';
  return specificWord;
}
```

Comment: Uh, yes, Got it, Thanks man!
Still don't know how to get the HTML in, but will figure a way out, Again Thanks for this

Comment: I think there is something still wrong, because If I put in YouTube only, it gets me into an Infinite loop, For Extension (Only) I will try Figuring it out...